# Scatter plot with infinitesimal point size in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Is it possible to do scatter plot in python, having points have minimal size of 1 pixel at given scale? I.e. points should not scale as I scale the plot and have size of 1 pixel always.

In pyplot

```
plt.scatter(d3_transformed[:,0], d3_transformed[:,1], s=1)
```

I still get fat point like this

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can change the marker to a point by setting `marker='.'`, and then further reduce its size by removing the outline using `linewidths=0`. Note that `markeredgewidth` does not work with `scatter`.

Consider this example. As you can see, the last line of points plotted (`marker='.', s=1, linewidths=0`) gives the smallest markers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

ax.scatter(x, np.ones_like(x)+0, marker='o', s=1, color='k')
ax.scatter(x, np.ones_like(x)+1, marker='o', s=1, color='k', linewidths=0)
ax.scatter(x, np.ones_like(x)+2, marker='.', s=1, color='k')
ax.scatter(x, np.ones_like(x)+3, marker='.', s=1, color='k', linewidths=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In scatterplot, the points have marker which is a symbol, like circle, and this symbol has also a border. I think the border is on by default. Try to turn off the bored, like set its width to 0.

http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markeredgewidth

Comment: Where to apply this function, sorry?

Comment: You can use `markeredgewidth` (or `mew`) as a scatter `arg`: `plt.scatter(d3_transformed[:,0], d3_transformed[:,1], s=1, markeredgewidth=0)`

Comment: or you can use 'smaller' symbol like `+` instead of the circle